# In a group $G$, if $a \in G$ is the only element such that its order is 2, prove that $G = C(a)$

Tags: group-theory, involutions

(i) As $C(a) \leq G $, $x \in C(a) \implies x \in G$. Hence $C(a) \subset G$.

(ii) How to prove $G \subset C(a)$?

I tried to start with $a^2 = e$ and manipulate this to get $ax = xa$, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does $C(a)$ mean the subgroup generated by $a$?

Comment: Or possibly the centralizer of $a$ in $G$?  If that's what you meant, then compute the order of $gag^{-1}$.

Comment: It's the centralizer of $a$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* What is the order of $x^{-1}ax$?

Comment: Wow, that was very obvious, I didn't notice it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact: in general, if $p$ is the *smallest* prime dividing $|G|$ and $N \unlhd G$ with $|N|=p$, then $N \subseteq Z(G)$.

**Proof** note that $G=N_G(N)$ and $G/C_G(N)$ can be embedded in Aut$(N) \cong C_{p-1}$ ($G$ acts by conjugation on $N$ with kernel $C_G(N)$). Since $p$ is minimal this implies $G/C_G(N)=\overline{1}$, whence $G=C_G(N)$, being equivalent to $N \subseteq Z(G)$.

Note that the uniqueness of your element $a$, implies $\{1,a\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.